# onMouseOver on div

Tags: html, hover, onmouseover

So I'm trying to get a onMouseOver to replace an image when the mouse is hovering over a div, unfortunately, as I have it right now it only replaces the image when the mouse is directly over the image, not the div, is there a way to get this to work?

Should I use a CSS to place the image, and replace the image on hover instead?

```
<div class="link">
     <a href="link.html">
          <img src="img.png" onMouseOver="this.src='hoverimg.png'" onMouseOut="img.png'"
          <div class="title">Title</div>
     </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer using CSS for this:

```
<div class="image-hover">
    Some title
</div>

.image-hover { background: url(...);}
.image-hover:hover { background: url(...);}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with CSS and background images. You also should not be using a block level element (div) inside of an inline element (a). I've swapped it for a span. For example:

```
<style type="text/css">
.link a {
    display:inline-block;
    background: url('img.png') top left no-repeat;
    width:(imagewidth)px;
    padding-top:(imageheight)px;
}
.link a:hover {
    background: url('hoverimg.png') top left no-repeat;
}
</style>

<div class="link">
     <a href="link.html">
          <span class="title">Title</span>
     </a>
</div>
```

The complete optimum would be combining the two images into what is called a sprite and use background-position.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS or jQuery. Most people will recommend that you use CSS because it is easier to debug:

If you want the image to change when you hover on the div, you can apply a :hover state to the div:

```
.link img{
    background: url("image1.png");
}

.link:hover img
{
    background: url("image2.png");
}
```

However you should note that this basically treats img as an inline-block element and does not change the src attribute.

---

jQuery will allow you to change the source, but it must be debugged if something goes wrong, and if JS is disabled, it will not run.

```
$(".link").hover(function(){
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", "image2.png");
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", "image1.png");
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xgQu/)